# inittab respawn of Node.js too fast

Tags: embedded, init

So I am trying to keep my Node server on a embedded computer running when it is out in the field. This lead me to leveraging inittab's respawn action. Here is the file I added to inittab:

`node:5:respawn:node /path/to/node/files &`

I know for a fact that when I startup this node application from command line, it does not get to the bottom of the main body and console.log "done" until a good 2-3 seconds after I issue the command.

So I feel like in that 2-3 second window the OS just keeps firing off respawns of the node app. I see in the error logs too in fact that the kernel ends up killing off a bunch of node processes because its running out of memory and stuff... plus I do get the 'node' process respawning too fast will suspend for 5 minutes message too.

I tried wrapping this in a script, dint work. I know I can use crontab but thats every minute... am I doing something wrong? or should I have a different approach all together?

Any and all advice is welcome!

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Surely too late for you, but in case someone else finds such a problem: try removing the `&` from the command invocation.

What happens is that when the command goes to the background (thanks to the `&`), the parent (init) sees that it exited, and respawns it. Result: a storm of new instantations of your command. 
Worse, you mention embedded, so I guess you are using busybox, whose init won't rate-limit the respawning - as would other implementations. So the respawning will only end when the system is out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

inittab is overkill for this. I found out what I need is a process monitor. I found one that is lightweight and effective; it has some good reports of working great out in the field. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_daemon

Using this would entail configuring this daemon to start and monitor your Node.js application for you.

That is a solution that works from the OS side.

Another way to do it is as follows. So if you are trying to keep Node.js running like I was, there are several modules written meant to keep other Node.js apps running. To mention a couple there are forever and respawn. I chose to use respawn.

This method entails starting one app written in Node.js that uses the respawn module to start and monitor the actual Node.js app you were interested in keeping running anyway.

Of course the downside of this is that if the Node.js engine (V8) goes down altogether then both your monitoring and monitored process will go down with it :-(. But its better than nothing!

PCD would be the ideal option. It would go down probably only if the OS goes down, and if the OS goes down then hope fully one has a watchdog in place to reboot the device/hardware.

Niko